# Are transceivers hot swappable?

Tags: networking, hardware, hp, nic, fiber

Are transceivers in general hot swappable, and if not, how do I find out if these are?

Using these adapters

```
665243-B21, HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 560FLR-SFP+
665249-B21, HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 560SFP+
```

and these transceivers

```
455883-B21,    HP BLc 10GB SR SFP+ opt
PSFP10-2321SF, PEAKOPTICAL SFP+ 10Km 1310nm DFB w/DDMI
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they're completely hot-swappable.

Think of them the same way as cables (*note the link lights*). Same for SFP+ direct-attach cables. It wouldn't make sense for them *not* to be hot-swappable. Heck, most network switches don't even have power switches :)

Answer (score 7):

Generally yes they are, certainly I've never come across any that weren't - in particular I know for a fact that the top three on your list are, not used the bottom one so can't say with the same degree of confidence.